# Submenus are hidden

Tags: html, css

I have tried applying a z-index in multiple places, but it doesn't seem to help.  I have attached a fiddle in addition to my HTML and CSS.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.  I have another website that I was working on and I applied z-index, and it worked perfectly, but I can't seem to apply the same principles here...
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mxplosionm203/b2pup79c/

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:700,700italic,400italic,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@font-face {
font-family : "'Oswald'";
font-style : normal;
font-weight : 400;
src : local('Oswald Regular'), local('Oswald-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v8/Y_TKV6o8WovbUd3m_X9aAA.ttf) format('truetype');
}
.err
{
 font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size : 12px;
 color: red;
}

body {
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 background-color: #F6F6F6;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
/*TITLE BAR SPECIFICATIONS*/
.titlebar{  
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;    
}
.titlebar > .info{
 max-width: 1175px;
   margin: 10px auto;
   text-align: right;
   color: #4F4F4F;
   line-height: 22px;
}
#content{
 max-width: 1175px;
 margin: 10px auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 border-style: solid;
}
#headlogo{
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 border-style: solid;
}

/*NAVIGATION BAR*/
#navbar {
    position: sticky;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 border: 5px solid #eeeeee;
 display: flex;
 background-color: white;
 max-width: 1175px;
 border-style: solid;
}

/* BE SURE TO INCLUDE THE CSS RESET FOUND IN THE DEMO PAGE'S CSS */
/* Resets */
nav a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px/1 Verdana;
    color: #000;
    display: block; }
nav a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
nav ul { 
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
nav ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/* Top-level menu */
nav > ul > li { 
    float: left;
    position: relative; }
nav > ul > li > a { 
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;}
nav > ul > li:first-child { margin: 0; }
nav > ul > li:first-child a { border: 0; }

/* Dropdown Menu */
nav ul li ul { 
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none; }
nav ul li ul li { 
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%; }
nav ul li ul a { padding: 10px 0; }
nav ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TestSite&reg;</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" href="images/octab.png" type="image/x-icon" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<!--BEGIN HEADER-->
<div class="titlebar">
<div class="info">Controls Technical Support: xxx-xxx-xxxx</div>
</div>


<!--NAVIGATION BAR LOGO-->
<div id="content">
<div id="headlogo">
<img src="images/AAON_WattMasterLogo.png" alt="WattMaster Controls, Inc.">
</div>

<div id="navbar">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>


<!--END HEADER-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `overflow: hidden` that is set on `#content`. Since your content div is only as tall as the menu, the submenu would have to overflow out of it, but that is currently hidden.

So you can remove `overflow: hidden` or make content taller so that the submenu div is not needing to overflow beyond the bottom edge.

Comment: THANK YOU! My alignment is a little out of wack now, but I think I can fix that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from `#content` and set the position of `dropdown`

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b2pup79c/3/)

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:700,700italic,400italic,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@font-face {
font-family : "'Oswald'";
font-style : normal;
font-weight : 400;
src : local('Oswald Regular'), local('Oswald-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v8/Y_TKV6o8WovbUd3m_X9aAA.ttf) format('truetype');
}
.err
{
 font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size : 12px;
 color: red;
}

body {
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 background-color: #F6F6F6;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
/*TITLE BAR SPECIFICATIONS*/
.titlebar{  
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;    
}
.titlebar > .info{
 max-width: 1175px;
   margin: 10px auto;
   text-align: right;
   color: #4F4F4F;
   line-height: 22px;
}
#content{
 max-width: 1175px;
 margin: 10px auto;
 /* overflow: hidden; */
 white-space: nowrap;
 border-style: solid;
}
#headlogo{
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 border-style: solid;
}

/*NAVIGATION BAR*/
#navbar {
    position: sticky;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 border: 5px solid #eeeeee;
 display: flex;
 background-color: white;
 max-width: 1175px;
 border-style: solid;
}

/* BE SURE TO INCLUDE THE CSS RESET FOUND IN THE DEMO PAGE'S CSS */
/* Resets */
nav a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px/1 Verdana;
    color: #000;
    display: block; }
nav a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
nav ul { 
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
nav ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/* Top-level menu */
nav > ul > li { 
    float: left;
    position: relative; }
nav > ul > li > a { 
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;}
nav > ul > li:first-child { margin: 0; }
nav > ul > li:first-child a { border: 0; }

/* Dropdown Menu */
nav ul li ul { 
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;}
nav ul li ul li { 
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%; }
nav ul li ul a { padding: 10px 0; }
nav ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TestSite&reg;</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" href="images/octab.png" type="image/x-icon" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<!--BEGIN HEADER-->
<div class="titlebar">
<div class="info">Controls Technical Support: xxx-xxx-xxxx</div>
</div>


<!--NAVIGATION BAR LOGO-->
<div id="content">
<div id="headlogo">
<img src="images/AAON_WattMasterLogo.png" alt="WattMaster Controls, Inc.">
</div>

<div id="navbar">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>


<!--END HEADER-->
```

Comment: This does solve my issue, but then I run into the navigation bar jumping up and overlapping the title bar, instead of staying aligned with the logo in the "content" div....but, it does give me something to work with, so thank you. :)

Comment: Apologies.  I tried to upvote, but I'm new to the forum, so my reputation was too low to publicly show the upvote :(

Comment: you can even upvote my answer with lower reputation :( @user3508197